# one sql trigger insert,update,delete for all tables in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012-express

is it possible to declare one Sql Trigger Insert, Update, Delete for all tables in the database instead of creating a separate trigger for each table? I just want a simple history of what actions have been taken e.g. TABLE A deletes a row ,TABLE B updates a row ,TABLE C Add new row .. and the trigger will insert a new row to another table with that information I want.

Comment: The best you can do is to define a procedure and create a trigger for each table then call it on every trigger. But, in order to do this you will have to figure out a way to pass the parameters to the procedure unless every table has the same parameter and it is this one you like to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a trigger can only be defined on a specified table.

You should read up on the auditing features of SQL Server (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx). They are more performant and more flexible in what you want to achieve. Unfortunately they are not available in the Express Edition.

Comment: hi, i have read about that feature but when i follow the instructions they are missing from the management studio, i guess that this may not supported in free edition of SQL EXPRESS 2012

Comment: management studio express is available as part of the 'tools' - you can get it for express also